# How to align tables and labels？

Tags: tables, align

How can I change the style of the first table to be the same as the second one?

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item[\textbf{c)}]
    \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
    \arrayrulecolor{SkyBlue}
    \begin{tabular}[H]{lr|c|c|c}
    \hline
    $p$ & $q$ & $\lnot q$ & $p\lor\lnot q$ & $(p\lor\lnot q)\rightarrow q$\\
    \hline
    T & T & F & T & T\\
    T & F & T & T & F\\
    F & T & F & F & T\\
    F & F & T & T & F\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{itemize}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help of `adjustbox` and use of `enumerate` list from the `enumitem` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for generating dummy text filler
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\alph*), labelsep=1em}
    \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
    \arrayrulecolor{SkyBlue}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\item   \lipsum[66]
\item   \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{tabular}{lr|c|c|c}
            \hline
            $p$ & $q$ & $\lnot q$ & $p\lor\lnot q$ & $(p\lor\lnot q)\rightarrow q$\\
            \hline
            T & T & F & T & T\\
            T & F & T & T & F\\
            F & T & F & F & T\\
            F & F & T & T & F\\
            \hline
            \end{tabular}}
\item
\end{enumerate}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
above solution is tested by recent version of MIkTeX (updated 2020.02.18). With older version of LaTeX installation similar result can be obtain with simpler solution (see @campa's and mine comments below).

Comment: Wouldn't `\begin{tabular}[t]` with `\firsthline` be easier?

Comment: @campa, in the first I check this possibility, but result was worse,  top line of the table was aligned (to my surprise) with the bottom of item label. I didn't investigated, if this is consequence of coloring of the `\arrayrule`. Please try this yourself and see, if you will obtain the same result as is obtained by use of the `adjustbox`

Comment: @campa, just now i check again your proposition. Coloring of table rules is not cause of miss align of table and enumerate label. As I said before, this simple solution not gives desired/expected result.

Comment: It's working for me... I'm unsure about posting an answer because my installation is somewhat old (TeXLive2017). Maybe something wrong with a recent one?

Comment: @campa, hm, this may be cause. I test both solution with MikTeX updated two days ago. I will ad note to my answer about this.